# How to set cache control using Azure cli?

Tags: azure

I'm using Azure Storage in my Django project to serve static files.

Google Pagespeed Insights says that there is no cache control header sent by Azure for static files.

I also have azure cli program installed. Is it possible to set cache control options via it (like described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content/))?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately from my research it does not seem possible, but you can use the node SDK to do it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860444/6338845

As such I have filed an issue on Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/3059